# Client Error: ValidationException error when trying to call the CreateModel Operation - Build my own container

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, roles, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to build my container and tag it to the docker Image created in the ECR Repository.
I am receiving a Validation Exception error and it is not able to access the Model output placed the S3 bucket. I have checked the IAM policy associated with it and it had the sts: AssumeRole and s3:getObject permissions with the associated role. Can anyone please help in identifying the cause of the error.

The container looks something like below:
_container = {
    'Image':        MULTI_MODEL_SKLEARN_IMAGE, # Docker Image inside the ECR Repository
    'ModelDataUrl': _model_url, # Model URL Location 
    'Mode':         'MultiModel'
    }

and the error image is [Error Message being generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrjaF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring that your IAM role also has s3:ListBucket permissions.